# Laravel artisan db:seed not seeding new record added to the Seeder class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I had some record in table inserted by SomeTableSeeder, I have deleted records from table and updated the SomeTableSeeder (added one more record). When I am running the `php artisan db:seed --class=SomeTableSeeder`, the new record I added later is not getting inserted in the database. Old record is getting inserted only. Any idea why?

**Note:** I am using remote database host. If that's the reason then new migrations should also not run. New migrations are running only newly added record in old table seeder is not inserting any record.
I have tried creating new seeder, I am getting error
`Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [NewTableSeeder] does not exist.`

Comment: did you try php:artisan cache:clear ?

Comment: run `composer dump-autoload` it is basic issue with laravel

Comment: new seeder is working but old seeding is not inserting new record after `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your DB is connecting correctly, don't forget to instruct the general seeder - DatabaseSeeder.php in <<your_project>>/database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php to seed the database. Your tables should be listed in the run method: `\App\Models\User::factory(20)->create();`